# How to create custom labels for issues on GitHub?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I've noticed that some organizations on GitHub have different labels that they can apply to issues.

For example, one organization that I am a part of allows any of these labels to be applied:

[image: many labels]

However, on my personal account, I am limited to only these labels, and I can't find a way to create my own custom ones:

[image: my labels]

Any ideas on how I can go about creating my own?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It looks like you might be accessing GitHub on a mobile device, which likely exposes a somewhat different interface.

On the full web interface, simply navigate to `https://github.com/:user/:repo/labels` and click the green "New label" button at the top right. Existing labels can be edited or deleted on the same page.

You can also get to this page by clicking on "issues" and then "labels".

Comment: What about organisation? How do we create issue-labels for organisation, and credential (password) are we going to pass in? :)

Comment: Is there a way to navigate to this place? (I was expecting to find it in the settings.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, on the desktop site go to the **Issues** tab, then click the **Labels** button. The mobile version doesn't seem to have a labels screen, but you can click the "Desktop version" link at the bottom right and go from there. You can return to the mobile version using the big grey link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 51):

Here's a quick GIF to make the process as easy as it can be. (recorded at my [GitHub profile](http://github.com/ahmadawais))

> ⚡️ GIF —
>
> [image: create github labels]

Labels can be applied to issues and pull requests to signify priority, category, or any other information that you find useful.

▶ On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

1. Under your repository name, click  Issues or  Pull requests.
2. Issues Labels buttonNext to the search field, click Labels.
3. Click New Label to create a new label, or click Edit to edit an existing one.
4. In the text box, type your new label name.
5. Select a color for the label from the color bar. You can customize this color by editing the hexadecimal number above the color bar.

[image: label color]

6. Click Create Label to save the new label.

I hope it helps. Upvote it if it does.

Comment: This was great, the official instructions say click next to the search box, but as  your gif shows, is the Filter box.

Answer (score 5):

The ui makes it hard to find!

You should be able to go to https://github.com/your_username/your_repo/labels

There's a github blog post that explains this in detail. 
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-editing-labels-for-issues-and-pull-requests/

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, then you might want to try using my python script (or creating something similar) so that you can set up your own labels for each new repository...

https://github.com/martinpeck/gh-issue-label-generator

Comment: You can suggest that people use your tools but you have to make the authorship explicit, otherwise the community considers it to be spam. Also, you should really explain how to use the tool. Otherwise, this makes your answer a link-only answer.